# How to rename files with a specific name structure?

Tags: shell-script, rename

How to write a shell script to rename the file in linux?

Ex:

```
234-2020-08-06-12-13-14-abc_up.csv
```

is renamed to

```
234-abc_up-2020-08-06-12-13-14.csv
```

Comment: Does your filename have a specific structure? E.g., in you example, one could just separate the string into substrings by dashes, erase the last substring and insert it in the second field. Please, specify the structure of filenames you have in mind, since every substring manipulation depends on that.

Comment: Structure of is: 234-2020-08-06-12-13-14-abc_up.csv (this will generate daily-dynamic file) to 234-abc_up-2020-08-06-12-13-14.csv
note:: 2020-08-06-12-13-14(yyyy-mm--dd-hh-mm-ss)

Comment: Thank you. If you can, edit the question with this new information, so it is clear to everyone.

Comment: You may get `rename` command which can be set to do what you want (using `sed` syntax, as you see in the answers), just most handy because you do not need a second step

Answer (score 0):

This shell script would do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
old_filename=$1
IFS='-' read -r -a arr <<< $old_filename    # read dash-separated substrings into the array 'arr'
tmpsub=${arr[7]%.csv.gz}                    # extract 7th substring, stripping out the file extension
for i in $(seq 6 -1 1)                      # shifts right the substrings
do                                          # in the array by one 
    arr[$(($i+1))]=${arr[$i]}               # position, starting by 1
done
arr[1]=$tmpsub                              # set the substring 1 to the value of the previous 7th substring
new_filename=$(printf -- "-%s" "${arr[@]}") # join the substrings into a dash separated string
new_filename=${new_filename:1}".csv.gz"     # add the extension
mv $old_filename $new_filename              # rename the file
```

If you name it, e.g., `rename_csv.sh`, and make it executable with `chmod`, you can call it with just the original filename as input as follows:

```
./rename_csv.sh 234-2020-08-06-12-13-14-abc_up.csv.gz
```

It does not show any output, but it renames the file as it should.

Comment: I don't know of any another way to insert a value at a specific index in a bash array, without explicitly doing a reverse cycle. That would probably depend on the fact that bash arrays are not implemented as linked lists, so no efficient insertion can be performed. Anyway, I am curious to know if there is another way around  (bash only of course).

Answer (score 0):

You could try `sed` for the filename transformation (the syntax implies GNU `sed`):

Example:

```
echo "234-2020-08-06-12-13-14-abc_up.csv" | sed -E 's/(.*)-([[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){5})-([^.]+).csv/\1-\4-\2.csv/'
234-abc_up-2020-08-06-12-13-14.csv
```

This will look for

- "any string" (stored in "capture group" 1), followed by
- a timestamp in `YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss` notation (i.e. 4 digits, and then 5 times "dash, followed by 2 digits"), stored in "capture group" 2, and then
- "any string up to but excluding the first period encountered", stored in capture group 4.

It will replace this pattern with "capture group 1", "capture group 4", "capture group 2", followed by `.csv`, which should meet your requirements.

*If your `sed` doesn't understand POSIX character classes, replace `[[:digit:]]` by `[0-9]`.*

So, a shell script might look like

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

fname="$1"
newname="$(sed -E 's/(.*)-([[:digit:]]{4}(-[[:digit:]]{2}){5})-([^.]+).csv/\1-\4-\2.csv/' <<< "$fname")"

mv "$fname" "$newname"
```

Make sure to test it first, by replacing the `mv` line with

```
echo "Would now execute 'mv $fname $newname'"
```

If you are not using `bash`, you will have to change the command-substitution to

```
newname="$(echo "$fname" | sed -E etc.)"
```